# Wordpress Sub-Menus are not displaying correctly on mobile phones

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My wordpress site's menus are not showing correctly on mobile phone. When I tap on the menu and then select the sub-menu from it, the sub-menu doesn't open beneath the main menu (as dropdown) but it hides into the right-side. Sub-menus are working correctly on computer/laptop screen but creating issue with mobile phones. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Following is the code for sub-menu column split:

```
.sub-menu { 
    width: 480px;
    display: grid; 
    grid-template-columns: 1 1; 
}


.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}



.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
float: left;
}


.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
float: right;
}
```

**Link of Menu Webpage:** [nawishta.com](https://nawishta.com)

Answer (score 0):

On mobile devices (you already got a class for this) you can reset the width of your unordered list:

```
.mobile-menu .item-active > ul { width: auto; }
```

If it does not work, try adding a `!important` like `width: auto !important;`.

Comment: I have applied this CSS, and now the sub-menu is entirely now showing. I wanted to show sub-menus beneath the parent item like (dropdown list) as when menu expands